# Keep getting: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, passwords

I'm working on a password reset feature for my django application.

I'm following along using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&t=924s

Everything works great but I get this error when I give the email and press enter on password-reset/:

```
NoReverseMatch at /password-reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here's my main/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("password-reset/", auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_form.html'),name="password_reset"),
    path("password-reset/done/", auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_done.html'),name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_confirm.html'),name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path("password-reset-complete/", auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_complete.html'),name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

password_reset_complete.html

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}

{% block content %}


<div class = "alert alert-info">Your password has been reset.</div>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Sign In Here </a>


{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_form.html

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
            <button style="background-color:darkblue; color:white" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Request Password Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_done.html

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div> An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password</div>

{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_confirm.html

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
            <button style="background-color:darkblue; color:white" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
        </form>
    </div>    

{% endblock %}
```

The tutorial didn't change anything in the views.py file if I'm not mistaken.

I've done everything in the tutorial yet I still get this error.

Thanks

Comment: show us your template, views, urls.

Comment: Just added those changes, thanks

Comment: You have a typo here: `<a href="{% url 'login %}"> Sign In Here </a>` should be `'login'`

Comment: Thank for noticing that, unfortunately, the issue is still there.

Comment: is the <uidb64> same as what it is showing when the error occurs.

Comment: In part of the error it says: {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}